# setting CPU entitlement for AIX 6.1

Tags: aix

Hi I would like to understand LPAR entitlement's better.

If I have a system that is running AIX 6.1 with an uncapped LPAR, what do I lose by setting the entitlement low? Meaning theoretically if I need more CPU power and more CPU's are available then I should see additional Lpars unfold and get more power, does this unfolding cause a system performance hit?

Is there a formula for setting CPU entitlement for AIX 6.1?

Answer (score 2):

I know understand the issue.  Its more than just requesting extra resources

> any capacity used beyond an LPAR's entitled capacity isn’t guaranteed (as it might be some other LPAR's
>   entitlement)

Meaning that you can be forced down to 100% use when you really need more.
Lesson: Don't get your entitlement wrong.

http://www.ibmsystemsmag.com/aix/Micro-Partitioning_on_AIX/32920p1.aspx